# Unable to Extract the Text Content of Element using Class in Web Scraping

Tags: jquery, web-scraping

I am trying to make a Web Scraper using Javascript. I need to extract the number 1214 from this Element: -

```
<span class="ss-icon-user num-students left">
        1,214
    </span>
```

Now I have written this code for it :-

```
var students = $('.ss-icon-user num-students left');

var no_of_students = students.text();

console.log(no_of_students);
```

but it gives no output at all. I tried :-

```
console.log(no_of_students.length);
```

and it gives the output 0.

Can anyone tell me why am I unable to extract it? What changes do I have to make?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. The span has 3 different classes - ss-icon-user, num-students, and left. Your selector is looking for elements with the ss-icon-user class which have a child "num-students" TAG with in turn has a child "left" TAG. If you want to select multiple classes, you would do it like this:

```
var students = $('.ss-icon-user, .num-students, .left');
```

Note that this could potentially pull back multiple entries if more than one element has all three of these classes.

Comment: I get your point but I think there aren't supposed to be ',' in between? Also I am still not able to get it to work.There are Multiple such elements that I want to extract I have been doing them in a loop like : $('.ss-icon-user.num-students.left').eq(i); but its not working out. Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: You can also string the classes together as you noted, but it should work either way. Is the selector not returning anything? If not, are there frames / iframes at play here? If so you will have to access the dom of the frame in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
$('.ss-icon-user.num-students.left').html();
```

You need to put dot "." in every class inside your tag.